# Let's get critical: Sep 2014 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Magento Stack Exchange](http://magento.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://magento.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Final Results

- [How do I create a "Spend and Save" style promotion? 10% off $99, 15% off $149, 20% off $199 with no coupon](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/31376/how-do-i-create-a-spend-and-save-style-promotion-10-off-99-15-off-149-2)

**Net Score: 13** (Excellent: 15, Satisfactory: 8, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Estimating the amount of space products take up in the database](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/32160/estimating-the-amount-of-space-products-take-up-in-the-database)

**Net Score: 10** (Excellent: 12, Satisfactory: 12, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Reset "Use Default Value" for specific store view on all products](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/33339/reset-use-default-value-for-specific-store-view-on-all-products)

**Net Score: 9** (Excellent: 11, Satisfactory: 10, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Debugging: Sorry, no quotes are available for this order at this time](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/31216/debugging-sorry-no-quotes-are-available-for-this-order-at-this-time)

**Net Score: 9** (Excellent: 10, Satisfactory: 9, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [How to create a shopping cart rule - Get an certain item free if you spend over $50](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/31614/how-to-create-a-shopping-cart-rule-get-an-certain-item-free-if-you-spend-over)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 15, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [Benchmarking Magento performance between 2 servers](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/30343/benchmarking-magento-performance-between-2-servers)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 13, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [SOAP V2 - Getting gift message 'To' & 'From' information from the sales order](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/31919/soap-v2-getting-gift-message-to-from-information-from-the-sales-order)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 12, Needs Improvement: 6)

---

- [Force all products in store to have default value of "taxeable goods"](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/31039/force-all-products-in-store-to-have-default-value-of-taxeable-goods)

**Net Score: -3** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 10, Needs Improvement: 7)

---

- [One click subscription purchase with no shopping cart?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/32194/one-click-subscription-purchase-with-no-shopping-cart)

**Net Score: -13** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 14)

---

- [How to set an image which is already on the server as product image](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/32231/how-to-set-an-image-which-is-already-on-the-server-as-product-image)

**Net Score: -15** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 7, Needs Improvement: 15)

---

Answer (score 2):

My thoughts:

1. This site [Does not allow discussion about 3rd party modules](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/19116/magento-blog-extension-error). Such discussions -probably- finally go to SO.
2. Even though Magento is popular, it has not a so-wide scope to be recognized by people to have an own site.
3. Drupal SE site allows discussion about 3rd party modules like Webforms. Don't see any reason why such Magento site shouldn't allow that, since there are really popular / well-known modules out there. Will not negotiate or accept any of such possible reasons since Magento is a CMS/eCommerce mainly built from modules (it's like Drupal, but with ecommerce as built-in). That makes Magento SE a highly-undesirably-strict site which is not always so pleasant to visit. That brings to play a chicken-and-egg problem: posts have not as good as expected answers in quality and/or quantity.

Comment: It's not that we don't allow 3rd party product support - it is that the ecosystem is too vast for us to have an effective answer rate on these types of questions. As the community grows I'm sure we're willing to revisit this or make exceptions for the more popular products like M2E, Magmi, etc. As for your other feedback, I'm glad to hear your thoughts and opinions - and I want to help you get the answers you're looking for - but to be quite honest you have been a member for 6 months, have asked 0 questions and have answered only 2, both of which are critical to our work here.

Comment: This site is supported by a community of enthusiasts for  users of all skill levels. We make an effort to keep this open and friendly. We have been inundated with traffic since the freeze of the Magento Forums and we are struggling to cope. At one point we were the second-highest traffic site in the SE network with a mere fraction of the user base. 75% of users on this site have < 10 karma. We fight to make this an open and honest place for people to ask questions of all types - not just dev. It'd be better for you to join us in helping answer rather than shout from the sidelines.

Comment: Don't worry Luis, a new community is coming that will be entirely focused on extensions.  A place to get advice from peers, experts and even connect with developers, all in your own personal Magento sandbox of nearly any version that you can make and share within minutes.  I have to agree with Phil, Magento Stack Exchange just isn't the place for this.  Way too many questions would get totally lost.  Not to mention, it would often be very hard to get a specific question answered if everyone couldn't see the extension(s) in action.

Comment: @philwinkle in fact I deleted the few questions I did, since I misunderstood the conditions about the problems, and so the questions were not so useful to be in the KB. Magento is not the technology I use to work on, but a technology I'm forced to work on eventually. I don't have enough knowledge to be quite useful to answer here, unfortunately. I'm sorry if i sounded harsh with my answer, but I got upset when I saw questions I use to consider legitimate in SO, being closed bc they related 3rdp modules.

Comment: Wait, no :p, I double checked. I have questions done in Magento which are not deleted :p. I have 0 questions in META Magento, but 10 questions in Magento

Comment: You're right about that I stand corrected, the point remains that what we really need is people who are going to commit to help us